# Tools/techniques for exploring 2D, 3D level sets in high D spaces

Tags: visualization

I have some 5D data which I need to visually explore.  Currently, I am plotting a 3D grid of 2D graphs for various values. Basically, I have N images each containing an NxN matrix of graphs... kind of like a scatter matrix.  The $x$ and $y$ axes plot D$_0$, D$_1$, I read right through the matrix to move in D$_2$, down to move in D$_3$, and flip to the next image to move in D$_4$.

Right now, I'm just using [Eye of Gnome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_of_GNOME) to view these images and flip through the images.  I'm sure it's great for viewing vacation pics, but it doesn't provide a very good "flow" for exploring my space.  E.g. if I want to zoom in on a particular level set in D$_2$, D$_3$ (a few neighboring plots in the matrix grid), then flipping through the images in D$_4$ doesn't maintain the correct view.

I'm not tied to this grid-of-images technique... it's just what I'm doing right now, and illustrates my process.  Here's a gif illustrating what I'm doing (resized to fit filesize requirements):

[image]

Are there any good tools/techniques for exploring level sets in high D spaces?  Bonus points for ability to zoom to arbitrary resolutions in real time.